# why line-height doesnt work if display isnt inline-block?

Tags: html, css, frontend

this code shows multi line vertically centered in css.
why line-height:1.5 doesnt work if display isnt inline-block?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.center p {
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Centering</h2>
<p>In this example, we use the line-height property with a value that is equal to the height property to center the div element:</p>

<div class="center">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[code link in w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_line-height)

Comment: w3schools example is just single line text . add lines before trying

Answer (score 0):

because by default `p` is a block element so the `line-height:200px` used to center the inline content within the line box will have no effect because we have no linebox and no inline content.

By making the p `inline-block`, you create your inline content and the `line-height` will strike.

Or you can keep the block default display and you remove the line-height inside `p` so it will inherit the `200px` and the centring will apply inside `p`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.center {
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.center p {
  margin:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Centering</h2>
<p>In this example, we use the line-height property with a value that is equal to the height property to center the div element:</p>

<div class="center">
  <p>I am vertically and horizontally centered.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> On a block container element whose content is **composed of inline-level elements**, ... <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height)</sup>

Without `inline-block` you had no inline-level elements

Comment: @WeyersdeLange I have no idea what are you saying .. maybe read the question again

Comment: i just wanna know why line-height:1.5 has no effect if display isnt inline-block.by the way w3schools example is single line text.make it multi line and then try again.thnks

Comment: @tronoverflow that's what I am explaining. the issue is not the line-height:1.5 but the upper one. That line-height is used to disable the inheritance because line-height is inherited

Comment: @Temani Afif thank you i also have a better understanding now.